# Django login authentication with credentials from custome table(mysql) not working

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to login with credentials which is in my mysql database , but its not working.it works fine for admin credentials.

views.py

```
 def logauth(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate( username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                messages.error(request, 'if part : user is not  None')
                login(request, user)
                messages.error(request, '111')
                return redirect('emp')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'else part : user is None')
                return redirect('login_url')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

models.py

```
  class RegAuth(AbstractBaseUser):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        email = models.EmailField(unique="TRUE")
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
        registrationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        objects = UserManager()

        is_anonymous = "FALSE"
        is_authenticated = "TRUE"

        is_active = False
        is_superuser = True

        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "mobile"]

        class Meta:
            db_table = "bloggerauth"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'jayesh',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('polls.backends.MyBackEnd', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', )
```

Comment: did you add AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings

Comment: yes
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'polls.RegAuth'

Comment: What do you mean "with credentials which is in my mysql database"? How were those credentials created? And when you say "it's not working" what exactly is the behaviour? Authentication fails? You see an error?

Comment: in the model set `is_active=True`, and  also keep `is_superuser=False`. Because you do not want to make each created user a superuser.

Comment: @dirkgroten i have registration module which saves users detail in mysql table. now i am trying to login with email and password which is save in mysql tables. so while doing that i am not able to login....

Comment: Show us the code how you create the users on registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass email instead of the username in authenticate function:

```
user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

Because you have defined `USERNAME_FIELD` as email:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def logauth(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            messages.error(request, 'if part : user is not  None')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'else part : user is None')
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please provide valid credentials')
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

backends.py

```
class MyBackEnd(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        existing_user = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
        if not existing_user:
            # Checking the user UserData Custom DB.
            user_data = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
            if email == user_data.email:
                user = RegAuth.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return existing_user

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return RegAuth.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return False
```